# PySpark date_add returns NULL value

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, casting, databricks

I load data from excel file do df.
But in some columns date is write in integer format.
PySpark in Data Bricks resolve format type like double.
I would like add double value to 1899-12-30 date, and I use date_add function.

When I do like below:

```
df = df.select(col('Date_Column'), expr("date_add(to_date('1899-12-30', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 2)").alias('New_Date_Column'))
```

it's work, and I receive in correct format date like: 1900-01-01

But if I switch digit 2 on column from df then I receive Null value ;(

```
df = df.select(col('Date_Column'), expr("date_add(to_timestamp('1899-12-30', 'd/M/yy'), cast('Date_Column' as Integer))").alias('New_Date_Column'))
```

I try doing cast with use date_format to timestamp. I try to convert to string, but always in result was NULL value.

Comment: `to_timestamp('1899-12-30', 'y-M-d')`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Zach King & @Lamanus for answer,

I try convert date to many times to different type also like You suggest, but no result.

I would like say that my date '1899-12-30' it is constant and always is 1899-12-30, but iteration value I take from df.column which is in double format. And I think this is problem, because if I add constant value is not a problem.

I always receive new column in date or timestamp format, depend on use method to convert.

```
for filename in files_to_process:
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
      .option("header", "true") \
      .option("inferSchema", "true") \
      .option("dataAddress", "0!A1") \
      .option("maxRowsInMemory", 1000) \
      .load(data_src_folder+filename)
```

DataFrame is loaded from Excel file like below:

Answer (score 0):

As @Lamanus implied in a comment, the correct date format expression for `to_date()` and `to_timestamp()` here would be `to_date('1899-12-30', 'y-M-d')` not `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Also, since your date strings are already in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format you can use simply cast the string to a date, and Spark will correctly infer the Date value from the string.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Using PySpark imperative style
df.select(F.date_add(F.col('Date_Column').cast('date'), 2)).show()

# OR using Spark SQL expressive style
df.select(F.expr('DATE_ADD(CAST(Date_Column AS DATE), 2)').alias('Date_Column').show()
```

If you still receive `NULL` values in your result, the original DataFrame must have inequalities in its raw date string formats.